# unable to extract and read a particular part of link from a file

Tags: python, json, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically I was trying to scrape a Reddit link about game of thrones. This is the link: https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/wiki/episode_discussion, this has many other links! What i was trying was to scrape all the links in a file which is done! Now i Have to individually scrape every link and print out the data in individual files either csv or json.

Ive tried all possible methods from google but still unable to come to a solution! Any help would be helpful

```
import praw
import json
import pandas as pd    #Pandas for scraping and saving it as a csv

#This is PRAW.
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                     client_secret='',
                     user_agent='android:com.example.myredditapp:v1.2.3 (by /u/AshKay12)',
                     username='******',
                     password='******')

subreddit=reddit.subreddit("gameofthrones")

Comments = []
submission = reddit.submission("links")

with open('got_reddit_links.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
        print('season: ' + str(p['season']))
        print('episode: ' + str(p['episode']))
        print('title: ' + str(p['title']))
        print('links: ' + str(p['links']))
        print('')


submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    print(20*'#')
    print('Parent ID:',comment.parent())
    print('Comment ID:',comment.id)
    print(comment.body)
    Comments.append([comment.body, comment.id])
Comments = pd.DataFrame(Comments, columns=['All_Comments', 'Comment ID'])
Comments.to_csv('Reddit3.csv')
```

This code prints out the links, title and episode number. It also extracts data when the link is manually entered but there are over 50 links in the webiste so i extracted those and put it in a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you explain the problem you are facing in more detail? What information are you trying to extract from the links?

Comment: Just the comments. Every link in the link i posted above is about different episodes of GOT. The code can extract the comments if the link is manually entered. I am trying to automate it! Say the link has 50 links, it should extract all the comments from the 50 links to 50 files. Hope you understood me!

Answer (score -1):

You can find all episode blocks with the links, and then write a function to scrape the comments for each episode discovered by each link:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests, itertools, re
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/wiki/episode_discussion')
new_d = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'md wiki'}).find_all(re.compile('h2|h4|table'))
g = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_d, key=lambda x:x.name == 'h2')]
r = {g[i][-1][0].text:{g[i+1][-1][k].text:g[i+1][-1][k+1] for k in range(0, len(g[i+1][-1]), 2)} for i in range(0, len(g), 2)}
final_r = {a:{b:[j['href'] for j in c.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('redd\.it')})] for b, c in k.items()} for a, k in r.items()}
```

Now, you have a dictionary with all the links structured according to Season and episode:

```
{'Season 1 Threads': {'1.01 Winter Is Coming': ['https://redd.it/gsd0t'], '1.02 The Kingsroad': ['https://redd.it/gwlcx'], '1.03 Lord Snow': ['https://redd.it/h1otp/'], '1.04 Cripples, Bastards, & Broken Things': ['https://redd.it/h70vv'].....
```

---

To get the comments, you have to use `selenium` as well to be able click on the button to display the entire comment structure:

```
import time
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')

def scrape_comments(url):
  d.get(url)
  _b = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('button') if 'VIEW ENTIRE DISCUSSION' in i.text][0]
  _b.send_keys('\n')
  time.sleep(1)
  p_obj = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'_1YCqQVO-9r-Up6QPB9H6_4 _1YCqQVO-9r-Up6QPB9H6_4'}).contents
  p_obj = [i for i in p_obj if i != '\n']
  c = [{'poster':'[deleted]' if i.a is None else i.a['href'], 'handle':getattr(i.find('div', {'class':'_2X6EB3ZhEeXCh1eIVA64XM _2hSecp_zkPm_s5ddV2htoj _zMIUk6t-WDI7fxfkvD02'}), 'text', 'N/A'), 'points':getattr(i.find('span', {'class':'_2ETuFsVzMBxiHia6HfJCTQ _3_GZIIN1xcMEC5AVuv4kfa'}), 'text', 'N/A'), 'time':getattr(i.find('a', {'class':'_1sA-1jNHouHDpgCp1fCQ_F'}), 'text', 'N/A'), 'comment':getattr(i.p, 'text', 'N/A')} for i in p_obj]
  return c
```

Sample output when running `scrape_comments` on one of the urls:

```
[{'poster': '/user/BWPhoenix/', 'handle': 'N/A', 'points': 'Score hidden', 'time': '2 years ago', 'comment': 'Week one, so a couple of quick questions:'}, {'poster': '/user/No0neAtAll/', 'handle': 'N/A', 'points': '957 points', 'time': '2 years ago', 'comment': "Davos fans showing their love Dude doesn't say a word the entire episode and gives only 3 glances but still get's 548 votes."}, {'poster': '/user/MairmanChao/', 'handle': 'N/A', 'points': '421 points', 'time': '2 years ago', 'comment': 'Davos always gets votes for being the most honorable man in Westeros'}, {'poster': '/user/BourbonSlut/', 'handle': 'N/A', 'points': '47 points', 'time': '2 years ago', 'comment': 'I was hoping for some Tyrion dialogue too..'}.....
```

Now, putting it all together:

```
final_result = {a:{b:[scrape_comments(i) for i in c] for b, c in k.items()} for a, k in final_r.items()}
```

From here, you can now create a `pd.DataFrame` from `final_result` or write the results to the file.

Comment: Yes i Have been able to figure it out later on my code itself. Now just have to find out how to continue from a crash instance! Say it has been extracting data and you lost connection to internet. Continue from crash after establishing internet connection again is what I am trying for